# Showing curl curl of symmetric gradient is 0

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, tensors

I am trying to show that $curl\,curl\,(\mathcal E)=0$, where $\mathcal E$ represents the symmetric gradient, i.e., for vector-valued function $u(x_1,x_2)=(u_1(x_1,x_2),u_2(x_1,x_2))$
$$
\mathcal E(u)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_1 u_1 & \frac12(\partial_2 u_1+\partial_1 u_2)\\
\frac12(\partial_2 u_1+\partial_1 u_2) & \partial_2 u_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I know there is a formula sayinng that 
$$
curl\,curl\,= \nabla div - \Delta
$$
and I am tryinng to apply this formula. However, I got confused that, say $\mathcal E(u)$ is a 2 by 2 matrix, so $\Delta \mathcal E(u)$ should be a 2 by 1 vector. But $div(\mathcal E(u))$ is a 2 by 1 vector and $\nabla div \mathcal E(u)$ is then a 2 by 2 matrix... so their dimension does not match... where I am wrong? Also, I tried to explicitly write down the computation but they did not cancel to 0...

---

update: for a reference I found, they write $\nabla div - \Delta$ as a 2 by 1 vector, but no explicit formula can be found there...

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: How are you defining the curl of a matrix?

Comment: @ConnorHarris this is one point I confused on. I can not find a definition of curl of a matrix online...

Comment: If $\mathcal E(u)$ is a matrix then $\Delta \mathcal E(u)$ should be too. I guess the curl is probably taken columnwise?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis how you define $\Delta \mathcal E(u)$?

Comment: The component-wise Laplacian is the obvious choice; if this is not what you mean then you should tell us your definition. Taking it to be component-wise is the same thing as taking it to be column-wise (if you use the component-wise defintion of the Laplacian of a vector), which means the identity $\operatorname{curl}^2  =\nabla \operatorname{div} - \Delta$ will apply columnwise.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis The only thing I found in reference I have so far is they treat $\nabla div - \Delta$ as a 2 by 1 vector. So I guess $\Delta \mathcal E$ is taken columnwise?

Comment: So you don't know what the curl of a matrix is, and you want to prove that the curl of the curl of a matrix is zero? This doesn't make any sense to me. Can you give more context? Is this an exercise in a textbook? Is this a result you need to prove some other theorem?